# part of the code does not work or grate loop error

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

When I try to run the code, I get an error:

> epoch_x, epoch_y = zetta
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

```
 for epoch in range(epochs_no):
     epoch_loss = 0
     for _ in range(int(1876536/batch_size)):
         data_size=1876536

         for l in range(data_size):
             zetta=0
             k=0

             for k in range(11):
                 k=k+1
                 if k==11:
                     zetta=zetta+1
                     k=0
                     epoch_x, epoch_y = zetta
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"zetta" is an int. You are trying to split it into two parts and assigning them to epoch_x and epoch_y. This doesn't work, comma assigning only works with "iterable" objects, for example:

```
x, y, z = [1,2,3]
```

makes x = 1, y = 2, and z = 3.

In your case, if you want epoch_x and epoch_y to both equal zetta, you need to do:

```
epoch_x, epoch_y = zetta,zetta
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

zetta at the end is an int. how do you expect to split it into two properties epoch_x and epoch_y